# FIPS integrity test failed

Tags: centos, boot, openssl

I recently enabled the fips module in my CentOS 6 machine using [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Federal_Standards_And_Regulations-Federal_Information_Processing_Standard.html).

During reboot, the system halted with this error:

```
SELF TEST FAILED (/usr/lib64/hmaccalc/sha512hmac.hmac)
dracut: FATAL: FIPS integrity test failed
dracut: Refusing to continue
```

Here's the relevant portions of sshd_config:

```
Protocol 2
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
Macs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

What would cause the self test failure?

Comment: What **exactly** did you do? You've cited bits of `sshd_config`, but that's irrelevant (it's relevant to being FIPS-compliant, it's not relevant to whether your system works). What matters is what files are verified during boot and how the verification was set up. Is FIPS mode even supported on CentOS?

Comment: I followed the steps in the link included in the first line of the question.    CentOS comes with a fips openssl module, you don't have to build it anymore.  I have it working on one machine, but the second one fails as described above.